# Why does Microsoft's implementation of std::string require 40 bytes on the stack?

Tags: c++, string

Having recently watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPR8h4-qZdk) about facebook's implementation of string, I was curious to see the internals of Microsoft's implementation. Unfortunately, the string file (in `%VisualStudioDirectory%/VC/include`) doesn't seem to contain the actual definition, but rather just conversion functions (e.g. atoi) and some operator overloads.

I decided to do some poking and prodding at it from user-level programs. The first thing I did, of course, was to test `sizeof(std::string)`. To my surprise, std::string takes 40 bytes! (On 64-bit machines anyways.) The previously mentioned video goes into detail about how facebook's implementation only requires 24 bytes and gcc's takes 32 bytes, so this was shocking to say the least.

We can dig a little deeper by writing a simple program that prints off the contents of the data byte-by-byte (including the c_str address), as such:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string test = "this is a very, very, very long string";

    // Print contents of std::string test.
    char* data = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&test);
    for (size_t wordNum = 0; wordNum < sizeof(std::string); wordNum = wordNum + sizeof(uint64_t))
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(uint64_t); i++)
            std::cout << (int)(data[wordNum + i]) << " ";

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    // Print the value of the address returned by test.c_str().
    // (Doing this byte-by-byte to match the above values).
    const char* testAddr = test.c_str();
    char* dataAddr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&testAddr);

    std::cout << "c_str address: ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(const char*); i++)
        std::cout << (int)(dataAddr[i]) << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This prints out:

```
48 33 -99 -47 -55 1 0 0
16 78 -100 -47 -55 1 0 0
-52 -52 -52 -52 -52 -52 -52 -52
38 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
47 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
c_str address: 16 78 -100 -47 -55 1 0 0
```

Examining this, we can see that the second word contains the address that points to the allocated data for the string, the third word is garbage (a buffer for Short String Optimization), the fourth word is the size, and the fifth word is the capacity. **But what about the first word? It appears to be an address, but what for? Shouldn't everything already be accounted for?**

For the sake of completeness, the following output shows SSO (the string is set to "Short String"). Note that the first word still seems to represent a pointer:

```
0 36 -28 19 123 1 0 0
83 104 111 114 116 32 83 116
114 105 110 103 0 -52 -52 -52
12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
c_str address: 112 -9 79 -108 23 0 0 0
```

EDIT: Ok, so having done more testing, it appears that the size of std::string actually decreases down to 32 bytes when compiled for release, and the first word is no longer there. But I'm still really interested in knowing why that is the case, and what that extra pointer is used for in debug mode.

**Update:** As per the tip by the user Yuushi, the extra word appears to related to Debug Iterator Support. This was verified when I turned off Debug Iterator Support (an example for doing this is shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985982.aspx)) and the size of std::string was reduced to 32 bytes, with the first word now missing.

However, it would still be really interesting to see how Debug Iterator Support uses that additional pointer to check for incorrect iterator use.

Comment: Could you please adding more information? Such as MSVC++ Compiler version, solution platforms (note that you use 64bit platform doesn't mean compile platforms is x64, default when create project is x86), some additional information about optimization and debug in compile flag, etc. Just for detailed and good question. I don't know the answer anyway but your question seem interesting.

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure of the answer but since it's in debug mode only, I'd hazard a guess that it might have something to do with MSVCs debug iterator support.

Comment: @khôinguyễn Sorry for leaving that information out. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (with compiler version 19.00.24215), and it is configured to compile for 64 bit. When compiling for debug, optimization is turned off, and when compiling for release, the flag /O2 is used.

Comment: @Yuushi Ok, I think I've verified that this is the right answer. I turned off support for Debug Iterator Support (there's an example of doing this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985982.aspx)), and that made the size of std::string in a debug build reduce to only 32 bytes, with the first word now missing. Thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 use `xstring` instead of `string` to define `std::basic_string`

**NOTE:** This answer is applied for VS2015 only, VS2013 uses a different implementation, however, they are more or less the same.

It's implemented as:

```
template<class _Elem,
class _Traits,
class _Alloc>
class basic_string
    : public _String_alloc<_String_base_types<_Elem, _Alloc> >
{
// This class has no member data
}
```

`_String_alloc` use a `_Compressed_pair<_Alty, _String_val<_Val_types> >` to store its data, in `std::string`, `_Alty` is `std::allocator<char>` and `_Val_types` is `_Simple_types<char>`, because `std::is_empty<std::allocator<char>>::value` is `true`, `sizeof _Compressed_pair<_Alty, _String_val<_Val_types> >` is the same with `sizeof _String_val<_Val_types>`

class `_String_val` inherites from `_Container_base` which is a `typedef` of `_Container_base0` when `#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 0` and `_Container_base12` otherwise. The difference between them is `_Container_base12` contains pointer to `_Container_proxy` for debug purpose. Beside that `_String_val` also have those members:

```
union _Bxty
    {   // storage for small buffer or pointer to larger one
    _Bxty()
        {   // user-provided, for fancy pointers
        }

    ~_Bxty() _NOEXCEPT
        {   // user-provided, for fancy pointers
        }

    value_type _Buf[_BUF_SIZE];
    pointer _Ptr;
    char _Alias[_BUF_SIZE]; // to permit aliasing
    } _Bx;

size_type _Mysize;  // current length of string
size_type _Myres;   // current storage reserved for string
```

With `_BUF_SIZE` is 16.

And `pointer_type`, `size_type` is well aligned together in this system. No alignment is necessary.

Hence, when _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 0 then `sizeof std::string` is:

```
_BUF_SIZE + 2 * sizeof size_type
```

otherwise it's

```
sizeof pointer_type +  _BUF_SIZE + 2 * sizeof size_type
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer! However, I am a little curious as to how you found this out. Could you point me in the direction of the resource you used to discover this information? I'd be very interested in looking at the source code for all of this.

Comment: In Visual Studio, you can right click and peak definition, you will need a bit of knowledge about template, SFINAE to trace it